# C++: A Lingering 'ghost' window appears..?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, console

My program - among other things - changes the console window appearance (mainly the window size and border).
Now on *my* computer, everything is working perfectly at the moment, but when I run the application in *VirtualBox*, or on a *different* computer, I get the following:

[image: what is happening]

The window on the top-left corner of the image is not actually a window. It's an image of a window, that you can't click. (mouse clicks go through it)
You can get rid of it by stretching the selection rectangle on the desktop over it, or if you highlight (for example) a button that is under it. Also, you can move a window over it, which makes it disappear completely.

The black rectangle on the bottom-right corner of the image is my console window, which is displayed correctly.

My question is, how to get rid of the 'ghost' window with C++?
I tried Googling a bit, but all I could find was `ChangeDisplaySettings(0, 0);`, which on my computer doesn't do anything (probably because I don't even have this problem on my computer), and in VirtualBox, it first appears to momentarily make the console window fullscreen and then back to the way it was. (the screen flickers the first time you run the application)
Although it does remove the ghost window, I don't want the screen to flicker like that, so this is not what I'm looking for.

EDIT:
As I can't really figure out what would be relevant code for this problem, I'll just dump pretty much all the code that has anything to do with changing the window itself in my program.

```
CSBIEx.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hCon, &CSBIEx);
CSBIEx.dwSize.X = 49;
CSBIEx.dwSize.Y = 21;
SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hCon, &CSBIEx);
srWnd.Bottom = 20;
srWnd.Left = 0;
srWnd.Right = 48;
srWnd.Top = 0;
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hCon, TRUE, &srWnd);
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rClnt);
rClnt.top += 1;
rClnt.bottom -= 2;
rClnt.right -= 1;
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
exStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
exStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle);
BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, ((rScr.right / 2) - rClnt.right / 2) - 1, (rScr.bottom / 2) - rClnt.bottom / 2, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOSIZE);
SetWindowRgn(hWnd, CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClnt), 1);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
//ChangeDisplaySettings(0, 0);
```

2ND EDIT:
I don't know if it's of any help, but I noticed that if I use `ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);` instead of `ChangeDisplaySettings(0, 0);` it doesn't do anything. That's pretty weird considering that `NULL` is `#define`d `0`..
If no one can figure anything out, I'll probably just end up using `ChangeDisplaySettings(0, 0);`.

Comment: Can you make a [short, self contained and correct example](http://sscce.org/) that you can show us? It's very hard to guess what's wrong without seeing any code.

Comment: This is the downside of changing a windows's settings behind its owner's back. Things don't get drawn or cleared properly as the window proc has no idea what you've done.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's really difficult for me to give any relevant code, since I can't actually replicate this on my own computer, but I'll try to add some code as best as I can. Just a moment.

Comment: A general hint: Don't clear the error code, call a function and check if there's an error code. Check the return values of functions instead. If you read the documentation for [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is states that some function sets the "error" code on success too.

Comment: I've always found SetWindowPos liable to leave occasional junk on the screen unless the `SWP_NOCOPYBITS` flag is used. (I can't say whether this will be helpful in this case, though. I've only ever used it for moving child windows with no nonclient area.)

Comment: @TomSeddon Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't there a function that would like.. refresh all windows? Or something along those lines..?

Comment: Click on the desktop and hit F5.  Does that clear the ghost image?  If so, the problem is Explorer doesn't know you've changed the window and isn't repainting its own window (the desktop).  If you can find a way to tell Explorer to refresh, that should solve the problem.

Comment: It goes away if the 'ghost' image is directly above the desktop, and not on any other window(s).

Comment: One final suggestion - try `InvalidateRect` with `NULL` as the window handle, and (I suppose) `NULL` as the `RECT`. See the docs - this (allegedly) invalidates and redraws every window, which hopefully will get rid of the lingering junk. (The docs do say this is "not recommended" - so don't forget to feel bad if it works.)

Comment: InvalidateRect(NULL, NULL, TRUE); seems to be working. And for some reason (even though it's more dangerous), I like it more than ChangeDisplaySettings();. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Otherwise, I'll answer it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InvalidateRect(NULL, NULL, TRUE);
```

Was the thing that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running an "Aero" theme on your computer? If so, switch to the classic theme. Betcha you will see the problem manifest itself. I think your app is not handling the WM_PAINT message properly. The Aero themes send far fewer WM_PAINT messages. The OS does the painting with bitmaps that it saves.

EDIT: Try calling these with the new dimensions:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleDisplayMode(
    _In_       HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
    _In_       DWORD dwFlags,
    _Out_opt_  PCOORD lpNewScreenBufferDimensions
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleWindowInfo(
  _In_  HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  BOOL bAbsolute,
  _In_  const SMALL_RECT *lpConsoleWindow
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can also try sending yourself a WM_PAINT message with DispatchMessage.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I can see the bug on my computer too after turning Aero off. The problem is that it's a console application, so I can't handle WM_PAINT message (or ANY message for that matter).. What should I do?